# Running a sequential trigger

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I have my own triggers in my database. But my customer wants customizations.

I need to give a trigger order according to the priorities he wants.

I'm aware that I can do all of them with 1 trigger, back-to-back if.

But I want to custom_xCompanyTrigger the trigger my customer wants and put it in the order I want.

If there is more than one trigger, it works either in the order of the create or in the order of the name, I could not understand it.

In this way, how should I go about customizing on a customer basis?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [city] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [date] [date] NULL,
    [value] [int] NULL,
    [islocked] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([name], [city], [date], [value], [islocked]) VALUES (N'John', N'Berlin', CAST(N'2022-01-02' AS Date), 10,1)
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([name], [city], [date], [value], [islocked]) VALUES (N'Marty', N'Istanbul', CAST(N'2022-01-03' AS Date), 20, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([name], [city], [date], [value], [islocked]) VALUES (N'Aila', N'Washington', CAST(N'2022-01-05' AS Date), 30, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([name], [city], [date], [value], [islocked]) VALUES (N'Aise', N'Moskova', CAST(N'2022-01-01' AS Date), 40, 1)
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
create TRIGGER MyTable_Trigger_Delete2 ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER DELETE AS

BEGIN

  /* Control-2 */
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED WHERE date<='2022-01-04')>0)

        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Control-2 worked.'
            RAISERROR ('You cannot delete records before January 5th.', 16, 1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
     else
           PRINT 'Control-2 passed.'


END
```

```
create TRIGGER MyTable_Trigger_Delete1 ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER DELETE AS

BEGIN

  /* Control-1 */
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED WHERE islocked=1)>0)

        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Control-1 worked.'
            RAISERROR ('You cannot delete a locked recording.', 16, 1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
     else
           PRINT 'Control-1 passed.'

END
```

```
select * from MyTable
```

| name | city | date | value | islocked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Berlin | 2022-01-02 | 10 | 1 |
| Marty | Istanbul | 2022-01-03 | 20 | 1 |
| Aila | Washington | 2022-01-05 | 30 | 1 |
| Aise | Moskova | 2022-01-01 | 40 | 1 |

```
delete from MyTable where city='Berlin'
```

```
Msg 50000 Level 16 State 1 Line 11
You cannot delete records before January 5th.
Msg 3609 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

```
select * from MyTable
```

| name | city | date | value | islocked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Berlin | 2022-01-02 | 10 | 1 |
| Marty | Istanbul | 2022-01-03 | 20 | 1 |
| Aila | Washington | 2022-01-05 | 30 | 1 |
| Aise | Moskova | 2022-01-01 | 40 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BtsxCWYF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the system stored procedure [sp_settriggerorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-settriggerorder-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to set the first and last `AFTER` triggers to be run on a table.

As per the docs on [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

> You can specify only one first and one last AFTER trigger for each INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE operation on a table. If there are other AFTER triggers on the same table, they're randomly run.
>
> If an ALTER TRIGGER statement changes a first or last trigger, the first or last attribute set on the modified trigger is dropped, and you must reset the order value by using sp_settriggerorder.

Also, further down as a note in the same docs:

> There's no defined order in which multiple triggers defined for a specific event are run. Each trigger should be self-contained.

So outside of specifying the first and last triggers for each applicable DML statement on a table, the remaining triggers have no defined order of execution.

To accomplish close to your goals, I'd recommend creating a single trigger that calls a shell stored procedure you also create. Set that trigger to run last (or first if that's preferable) and then put the custom logic (or allow the customer to modify the procedure to implement the custom logic) in the order they want the code executed, so at least relatively speaking, the order of the custom code can be specified.

Comment: I like to reserve LAST for data auditing triggers.